# Using cc results in an error

Tags: gcc, cc

I had been using the command cc to compile the C programs that I write. Recently, I installed drush and removed it again (right now, I am using a site local drush). After that, when I am trying to compile a C program using cc, I am getting this :

```
The program 'drush' is currently not installed. You can install it by typing:
sudo apt install drush
```

I tried :

```
update-alternatives --config
```

But it says :

```
There is only one alternative in link group cc (providing /usr/bin/cc): /usr/bin/gcc
Nothing to configure.
```

What is the issue here?

Comment: what does `alias cc` shows?

Comment: @dlmeetei it says alias cc='drush cache-clear' ( I guess that you have located the issue. How can I fix the alias?)

Comment: @JoelJosephReji `unalias drush` to get rid of it in current terminal session. Also make sure it's not somewhere aliased in `.bash_aliases` or even `.bashrc` (both text/script files) in your home folder.

Comment: You can fix it by `alias cc=\`which gcc\` `

Comment: @dlmeetei note: you messed up your backticks. or stackoverflow syntax messed it up. whatever.

Comment: Thanks, @Jay, corrected

Answer (score 0):

As `drush` have updated `cc` as `alias cc='drush cache-clear'`. We need to map `cc` to reflect our desired value.

Ubuntu box shows `cc` as `/usr/bin/cc` which is symbolic link to `/usr/bin/gcc` though `/etc/alternatives/cc`. Hence, it should be safe alias `cc` to resolve your issue

```
alias cc=`which gcc`
```